# Creating new model in backbone?

Tags: javascript, object, backbone.js, new-operator

I want to create a new model based on some parameter. [JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/yahovose/2/edit?js,console,output)

```
var M1 = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: { type: 'one', value: 1 }
});

var M2 = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: { type: 'two', value: 2 }
});

var getModel = function(type) {
  var map = { 'one': M1, 'two': M2 };
  return map[type];
};

// Error in this line (Undefined is not a function)
var model = new getModel('two')();

console.log(model.get('value'));
```

I have tried several notations but could not pin-point the reason.

#### 1. This works fine

```
var mapModel = {
  'one': M1,
  'two': M2
};

new mapModel['two']();
```

#### 2. Does not work

```
var model = new (getModel('two')());
var model = (new getModel('two'))();
```

I do not understand what is undefiend and why I am seeing this error.

Comment: IMHO i would use following: no need in new outside of getModel function, i would place it inside (return new map[type]). then use getModel('two') to get model instacne.

Comment: @Evgeniy I am fine with using map but I want to understand the reason of error ?

Comment: @Evgeniy Thanks for your response. I understand the problem now and i have tried to explain it in some words. Feel free to edit the answer if you think there is a better explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it this case is better to update `getModel` function and delegate it creating model instances.Lets create factory from `getModel`

```
var getModel = function(type) {
    var map = { 'one': M1, 'two': M2 };
    return new map[type];
};
```

Then you can use it to get new instance of proper type model:

```
var model = getModel('two');
```

Comment: @Prinzhorn is right..You also meant to create a model factory. You just missed the term "factory" which carries a lot of weight here ;)
Happy to accept your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I have got the reason, I was facing the issue. Let's understand the mistakes one by one. [Working JSbin](http://jsbin.com/yahovose/21/edit?js,console,output)

**We need to fully understand the precedence of new operator.**

Sample #1

```
var model = new getModel('two')();
```

In this case, new is used with getModel method and we try to again call what is being returned by new getModel('two).

Sample #2, #3

```
var model = new (getModel('two')());
var model = (new getModel('two'))();
```

In these cases, whatever is returned from getModel('two') is called first and then instance is created.

**Solution**

```
var model = new (getModel('two'))();
```

Comment: Maybe move the `new` inside `getModel` and call it a factory? This will get rid of all the confusion (maybe rename to `createModel`).

Comment: @Prinzhorn That is a really nice suggestion. Why didn't I think so. You are all right.

Comment: @Prinzhorn Should you add an answer what you say, I will be happy to accept yours :)

Comment: I just realized Evgeniy already suggested that in the comment above.

Comment: @Prinzhorn thanks) if you don't mind i'll post this idea as alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping `new` operator in this factory function?

```
function createModel() {
  var object = new (arguments[0]);
  (arguments[0]).apply(object, [arguments[1]]);
  return object;
}

var model = createModel(getModel('two'));
var model2 = createModel(getModel('two'), { value: 4 });
console.log(model.get('value')); // 2
console.log(model2.get('value')); // 4
```

**Edit**
You can also combine the factory method with your current getModel

```
var getModel = function() {
   var map = {
     'one': M1,
     'two': M2
   };
   var type = arguments[0];
   var M = map[type];
   var obj = new M;
   M.apply(obj, [arguments[1]]);
   return obj;
};
var model = getModel('two');
console.log(model.get('value')); // 2
var model2 = getModel('two', { value : 4});
console.log(model2.get('value')); // 4
```